# Python-3.x range() with step in float format

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python-3.3.2. How can I use `range()`to achieve float type of step? Assume my code is:

```
for x in range(1.5,20,0.25):
    print(x)
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried `import numpy as np`, but there I got an error

Comment: You have to download numpy first. But check the other solutions - you can simply do `for x in range(6, 80): print x*0.25` without installing numpy.